# Issue when killing an app in iOS simulator

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

When I simulate my app on the iPad simulator (iOS 6) and simulate terminating the application, it takes me to a debug session within the main.m file. It highlights this method in green and says Thread 1: signal SIGKILL

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

```
 @autoreleasepool {
      return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
 }
```

}

When I go to run the app again (simulating terminating the app and reopening it again it brings me back to the viewController where I was when I killed the app, but it's completely frozen. Can't scroll, use the navigation toolbar or edit any text, etc etc. If I then go to the homescreen and back into the app again, I'm left with nothing but a blank black screen. Is there something I need to edit within the main.m file? I haven't touched anything in that file ever. Or is this potentially just how the simulator works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to main.m are not necessary, but you'll have to prepare your app for termination and re-set it when it comes alive again. See [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786) of the delegate methods. Esp. those described under "Monitoring App State Changes".